# NLP : Find syntactically similar subsequences from text

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Can someone suggest a suitable algorithm or a related paper for a scenario where we are given a text file and we have to group syntactically similar subsequences from the text file.

Something like : I request you to pass me a cup of of coffee & Can you please pass me a cup of coffee

Must be grouped under the same label as both convey similar meanings.

Comment: If you want to group together similar meanings, then it's *semantic*, not *syntactic*, similarity.

Comment: Try gensim: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/